# How to change ownership/permissions to folder inside VOLUME in Dockerfile created from another image?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos

USER jenkins
ENV PLUGIN_DIR=$JENKINS_HOME/plugins
RUN mkdir $JENKINS_HOME/plugins

RUN ls -aliF $JENKINS_HOME/
```

that results in no folder *plugins* present.

The same result when **root** user is used.

Workaround for this is to use WORKDIR:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos

USER jenkins
WORKDIR $JENKINS_HOME/plugins
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME/plugins

RUN ls -aliF $JENKINS_HOME/
```

but it results in *plugins* folder to be of *root*.

> 35539281 drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       6 May 26 21:45 plugins/

Same with user *root*:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos

USER root
WORKDIR $JENKINS_HOME/plugins
RUN chown jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME/plugins

RUN ls -aliF $JENKINS_HOME/
```

> 35539493 drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       6 May 26 21:52 plugins/

The *jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos* uses $JENKINS_HOME as VOLUME.

This somehow prevents creating a folder with custom ownership or permissions.

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

Create a folder *jenkins/plugins* and copy it into the image:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-centos

USER root
COPY --chown=jenkins:jenkins jenkins/ $JENKINS_HOME/

RUN ls -aliF $JENKINS_HOME/
```

it results in *jenkins* ownership:

> 2367864 drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    6 May 27 09:14 plugins/

As this is a workaround, the question still remains - how to do it in a proper way?